# Input from the keyboard in command line application

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, command-line

I am attempting to get the keyboard input for a command line app for the new Apple programming language Swift.

I've scanned the docs to no avail.

```
import Foundation

println("What is your name?")
???
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I managed to figure it out without dropping down in to C:

My solution is as follows:

```
func input() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
}
```

More recent versions of Xcode need an explicit typecast (works in Xcode 6.4):

```
func input() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
}
```

Comment: I like this, also, it can be compressed down to one line if you don't want to define a function, like if you only need to accept input once in a program:
`var input = NSString(data:  NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Comment: Is there a way to use this in the Playground to accept user input on the fly?

Comment: You cannot use this in playground. You have to use variables in there.

Comment: Note that you'll get newlines in the string with this. Strip them out with `string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())`

Comment: You'll also get strange characters if the user deletes a character, uses an arrow key, etc. AAAGGGGGHHHH WHY, Swift, Why?

Comment: I'm trying var input = NSString(data: NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput().availableData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) from jcmiller but I get something like this "Optional(25)" where "25" is the input I gave from the keyboard. Where is that "Optional()" coming from?

Comment: In Swift 1.2: `let inputString = NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String`

Comment: In Swift 2.0:     return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

Comment: Note that weird characters can be removed with additional routines.

Comment: ybakos, aramis, those characters do not manifest themselves if you use readLine (see my response).

Comment: Here's a tutorial using  Swift v2 that uses built in `input()`. `let userInput = input()` https://www.raywenderlich.com/114173/learn-to-code-ios-apps-with-swift-tutorial-2-your-first-project

Answer (score 147):

The correct way to do this is to use [`readLine`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641199-readline), from the Swift Standard Library.

Example:

```
let response = readLine()
```

Will give you an Optional value containing the entered text.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to get password kind of input?

Comment: For me, it just drops through this line with response = nil. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @PeterWebb - works fine in xcode terminal, falls through in playground :)

Comment: readLine was added after most of the original answers, so the attitude is a bit unwarranted IMHO

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: ```bash
plusone.swift:1:16: error: 'readLine(stripNewline:)' has been renamed to 'readLine(strippingNewline:)'
```

It seems like ``stripNewline`` have been renamed to ``strippingNewline`` in newer versions of Swift https://code.sealedabstract.com/CaffeinatedSwift/swift/commit/f912c8faf09d4d76f6f347d57a04fc866b767057

Comment: Corrected for Swift 3, SlimJim

Comment: [If stripNewline is true, newline characters and character combinations will be stripped from the result. **This is the default.**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641199-readline)

Answer (score 15):

It's actually not that easy, you have to interact with the C API. There is no alternative to `scanf`. I've build a little example:

**main.swift**

```
import Foundation

var output: CInt = 0
getInput(&output)

println(output)
```

**UserInput.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getInput(int *output) {
    scanf("%i", output);
}
```

**cliinput-Bridging-Header.h**

```
void getInput(int *output);
```

Comment: Oh boy - I wish there was something more trivial than this! I'm finding it difficult to adapt this for a string of characters.

Comment: It would be better to create a "UserInput.h" to store the function definitions,  and includes this file in "cliinput-Bridging-Header.h".

Comment: How would you build this from the terminal ?

Answer (score 11):

In general **readLine()** function is used for scanning input from console. But it will not work in normal iOS project until or unless you add **"command-line tool"**.

The best way for testing, you can do :

## 1. Create an macOS file

[image]

## 2. Use the readLine() func to scan optional String from console

```
 import Foundation

 print("Please enter some input\n")

 if let response = readLine() {
    print("output :",response)
 } else {
    print("Nothing")
 }
```

## Output :

```
Please enter some input

Hello, World
output : Hello, World
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**edit** As of Swift 2.2 the standard library includes `readLine`. I'll also note Swift switched to markdown doc comments. Leaving my original answer for historical context.

Just for completeness, here is a Swift implementation of `readln` I've been using. It has an optional parameter to indicate the maximum number of bytes you want to read (which may or may not be the length of the String).

This also demonstrates the proper use of swiftdoc comments - Swift will generate a <project>.swiftdoc file and Xcode will use it.

```
///reads a line from standard input
///
///:param: max specifies the number of bytes to read
///
///:returns: the string, or nil if an error was encountered trying to read Stdin
public func readln(max:Int = 8192) -> String? {
    assert(max > 0, "max must be between 1 and Int.max")

    var buf:Array<CChar> = []
    var c = getchar()
    while c != EOF && c != 10 && buf.count < max {
        buf.append(CChar(c))
        c = getchar()
    }

    //always null terminate
    buf.append(CChar(0))

    return buf.withUnsafeBufferPointer { String.fromCString($0.baseAddress) }
}
```

Comment: I like the swiftdoc comments, and the "public" access modifier, I hadn't seen that sort of thing in Swift before, but the CChar and the C-String seem to be a throwback to C and 8-bit character sets and Swift is all about Unicode text...or are command-line tools all ASCII??

Comment: I believe getchar() returns ASCII. Unicode terminals is a whole thing I didn't want to get into :)

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to link [libedit](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/) for proper line editing (arrow keys, etc.) and optional history support. I wanted this for a project I'm starting and put together a [basic example for how I set it up](https://github.com/neilpa/swift-libedit).

Usage from swift

```
let prompt: Prompt = Prompt(argv0: C_ARGV[0])

while (true) {
    if let line = prompt.gets() {
        print("You typed \(line)")
    }
}
```

ObjC wrapper to expose libedit

```
#import <histedit.h>

char* prompt(EditLine *e) {
    return "> ";
}

@implementation Prompt

EditLine* _el;
History* _hist;
HistEvent _ev;

- (instancetype) initWithArgv0:(const char*)argv0 {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // Setup the editor
        _el = el_init(argv0, stdin, stdout, stderr);
        el_set(_el, EL_PROMPT, &prompt);
        el_set(_el, EL_EDITOR, "emacs");

        // With support for history
        _hist = history_init();
        history(_hist, &_ev, H_SETSIZE, 800);
        el_set(_el, EL_HIST, history, _hist);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    if (_hist != NULL) {
        history_end(_hist);
        _hist = NULL;
    }

    if (_el != NULL) {
        el_end(_el);
        _el = NULL;
    }
}

- (NSString*) gets {

    // line includes the trailing newline
    int count;
    const char* line = el_gets(_el, &count);

    if (count > 0) {
        history(_hist, &_ev, H_ENTER, line);

        return [NSString stringWithCString:line encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

Lots of outdated answers to this question. As of Swift 2+ the Swift Standard Library contains the [readline()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641199-readline) function. It will return an Optional but it will only be nil if EOF has been reached, which will not happen when getting input from the keyboard so it can safely be unwrapped by force in those scenarios. If the user does not enter anything its (unwrapped) value will be an empty string. Here's a small utility function that uses recursion to prompt the user until at least one character has been entered:

```
func prompt(message: String) -> String {
    print(message)
    let input: String = readLine()!
    if input == "" {
        return prompt(message: message)
    } else {
        return input
    }
}

let input = prompt(message: "Enter something!")
print("You entered \(input)")
```

**Note that using optional binding (if let input = readLine()) to check if something was entered as proposed in other answers will not have the desired effect, as it will never be nil and at least "" when accepting keyboard input.**

This will not work in a Playground or any other environment where you does not have access to the command prompt. It seems to have issues in the command-line REPL as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple example of taking input from user on console based application: 
You can use readLine(). Take input from console for first number then press enter. After that take input for second number as shown in the image below:

```
func solveMefirst(firstNo: Int , secondNo: Int) -> Int {
    return firstNo + secondNo
}

let num1 = readLine()
let num2 = readLine()

var IntNum1 = Int(num1!)
var IntNum2 = Int(num2!)

let sum = solveMefirst(IntNum1!, secondNo: IntNum2!)
print(sum)
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 : If you continuously want input from keyboard , without ending the program, like a stream of input, Use below steps:

1. Create new project of type comnnad line tool
   [image: Command line project]

   2. Add below code in main.swift file:

      ```
      var inputArray = [String]()

      while let input = readLine() {

      guard input != "quit" else {

      break

      }

      inputArray.append(input)

      print("You entered: \(input)")

      print(inputArray)

      print("Enter a word:")
      }
      ```
   3. RunThe project and click the executable under Products folder in Xcode and open in finder
   4. Double click the executable to open it.
   5. Now enter your Inputs. Terminal will look something like this:
      [image]

Answer (score 0):

I swear to God.. the solution to this *utterly basic* problem  eluded me for YEARS. It's **SO simple**.. but there is so much vague / bad information out there; hopefully I can save *someone* from *some* of the bottomless [rabbit holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_hole) that I ended up in...

So then, lets's get a "string" from "the user" via "the console", via `stdin`, *shall we*?

```
[NSString.alloc initWithData:
[NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput availableData]
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

if you want it *WITHOUT* the trailing newline, just add...

```
[ ... stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                       NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet];
```

***`Ta Da!`***  ♥ ⱥᏪℯⅩ

Comment: Swift, the OP says Swift.

Comment: He said osx. It all compiles down to the same thing! Embrace your inner-ObjC!

Comment: There are people who write in Swift and will never learn Objective C. This is not about what it compiles down to.

Answer (score 0):

Since there were no fancy solutions to this problem, I made a tiny class to read and parse the standard input in Swift. You can find it [here](https://github.com/shoumikhin/StreamScanner).

**Example**

To parse:

```
+42 st_ring!
-0.987654321 12345678900
.42
```

You do:

```
let stdin = StreamScanner.standardInput

if
    let i: Int = stdin.read(),
    let s: String = stdin.read(),
    let d: Double = stdin.read(),
    let i64: Int64 = stdin.read(),
    let f: Float = stdin.read()
{
    print("\(i) \(s) \(d) \(i64) \(f)")  //prints "42 st_ring! -0.987654321 12345678900 0.42"
}
```

Comment: How to import the StreamScanner class?

Comment: @TimothySwan, just as explained in Installation section of Readme (https://github.com/shoumikhin/StreamScanner#installation).

So basically you can just add StreamScanner.swift file to your project.

Answer (score 0):

**Before**

[image]

*******************.

**Correction**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works in xCode v6.2, I think that's Swift v1.2

```
func input() -> String {
    var keyboard = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    var inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read space separated string, and immediately split the string into an array, you can do this:

`var arr = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)`

eg.

```
print("What is your full name?")

var arr = readLine()!.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)

var firstName = ""
var middleName = ""
var lastName = ""

if arr.count > 0 {
    firstName = arr[0]
}
if arr.count > 2 {
    middleName = arr[1]
    lastName = arr[2]
} else if arr.count > 1 {
    lastName = arr[1]
}

print("First Name: \(firstName)")
print("Middle Name: \(middleName)")
print("Last Name: \(lastName)")
```

Answer (score 0):

When readLine() function is run on Xcode, the debug console waits for input. The rest of the code will be resumed after input is done.

```
    let inputStr = readLine()
    if let inputStr = inputStr {
        print(inputStr)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to comment (I have not enough reps) on xenadu's implementation, because `CChar` in OS X is `Int8`, and Swift does not like at all when you add to the array when `getchar()` returns parts of UTF-8, or anything else above 7 bit.

I am using an array of `UInt8` instead, and it works great and `String.fromCString` converts the `UInt8` into UTF-8 just fine.

However this is how I done it

```
func readln() -> (str: String?, hadError: Bool) {
    var cstr: [UInt8] = []
    var c: Int32 = 0
    while c != EOF {
        c = getchar()
        if (c == 10 || c == 13) || c > 255 { break }
        cstr.append(UInt8(c))
    }
    cstr.append(0)
    return String.fromCStringRepairingIllFormedUTF8(UnsafePointer<CChar>(cstr))
}

while true {
    if let mystring = readln().str {
        println(" > \(mystring)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have now been able to get Keyboard input in Swift by using the following:

In my main.swift file I declared a variable i and assigned to it the function GetInt() which I defined in Objective C. Through  a so called Bridging Header where I declared the function prototype for GetInt I could link to main.swift. Here are the files:

main.swift:

```
var i: CInt = GetInt()
println("Your input is \(i) ");
```

Bridging Header:

```
#include "obj.m"

int GetInt();
```

obj.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <stdlib.h>

int GetInt()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%i", &i);
    return i;
}
```

In obj.m it is possible to include the c standard output and input, stdio.h, as well as the c standard library stdlib.h which enables you to program in C in Objective-C, which means there is no need for including a real swift file like user.c or something like that.

Hope I could help,

Edit: It is not possible to get String input through C because here I am using the CInt -> the integer type of C and not of Swift. There is no equivalent Swift type for the C char*. Therefore String is not convertible to string. But there are fairly enough solutions around here to get String input.

Raul

Answer (score -1):

The top ranked answer to this question suggests using the readLine() method to take in user input from the command line. However, I want to note that you need to use the ! operator when calling this method to return a string instead of an optional:

```
var response = readLine()!
```

Comment: Why the force-unwrap, `readLine()` returns optional for a reason, it's therefore unsafe to force-unwrap and doesn't really add anything to the example.

Answer (score -1):

```
var a;
scanf("%s\n", n);
```

I tested this out in ObjC, and maybe this will be useful.

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation
print("Enter a number")
let number : Int = Int(readLine(strippingNewline: true)!) ?? 0
if(number < 5)
{
    print("Small")
}else{
    print("Big")
}
for i in 0...number{
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.