# Xcode 6, Swift - read standard input (console) to string

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am new to Objective-C and XCode and I'm trying to learn something new. Is there any way to read string from stdin using swift ? Something like cin in C++ ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004776/input-from-the-keyboard-in-command-line-application

Answer (score 11):

Just as with Objective-C, you can use `NSFileHandle`:

```
let standardInput = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
let input = standardInput.availableData
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked for me, but I didn't think that it did at first because it only worked sometimes for me. 1) From within Xcode, which seems to me to have numerous problems with doing input from the console, it works for all of my keys, except for my digit keys from the ten-key pad, 2) From Terminal, all keys seem to work.

Comment: Here's what I got working: http://66.36.184.53/programming/languages/apple/swift/tutorials/swift-for-java-developers/io_reading-from-the-console

Comment: @kaydell  that link does not seem to work.  any chance you can post the code as an answer?  much appreciated.

Comment: @KinjalDixit, sorry for the bad link.  What I've decided to do inside of Xcode, is just to use the digit keys across the top of the keyboard, and use the Return key, rather than trying to use the 10-key pad.  When you deploy a command-line program to Terminal.app, all of the keys should work OK.