# Swift - Reading piped input

Tags: linux, swift, bash, xcrun

I created a "Shebang" swift script.

I am parsing the input arguments using `Process.arguments`

How can I read the "piped" information in the case it was piped into the script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift
import Foundation
for argument in Process.arguments {
// parse the input arguments
}

// if the input is piped into the script?:
// if PIPE??? { 
print("Handling pipe")
let pipe = NSPipe()
let handle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
let data = handle.readDataToEndOfFile()
print("End of pip")
}
```

Comment: Use standard input? http://stackoverflow.com/q/24046952/2088135

Comment: Thanks,I tried that but it freezes up.

Comment: print("Handling pipe")
        let pipe = NSPipe()
        let handle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        let data = handle.availableData
        print("End of pip")
        print(data)

Comment: Note the difference between `fileHandleForReading` in your attempt and `fileHandleWithStandardInput` as suggested in the linked answer.

Answer (score 2):

Changed from `NSPipe` to 

`NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
let data = pipe.availableData`

seems to do the trick.
Thanks to
@Tom Fenech