# How to read user input or stdin in Swift for Linux?

Tags: linux, swift

How to read *user input* or character stream from *standard input* in Swift for Linux?

Comment: I think `readLine` ( http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/func/readLine/ ) should work, however not tested on Linux

Comment: It reads until new-line, doesn't?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[readLine()](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/8d9ef80304d7b36e13619ea50e6e76f3ec9221ba/stdlib/public/core/InputStream.swift) works on Ubuntu 15:

> [Readline] Returns `Character`s read from standard input through the end of the
>   current line or until EOF is reached, or `nil` if EOF has already been
>   reached.

Example:

```
print("\nEnter your name:\n")
if let name = readLine() {
    print("\nHello \(name)!\n")
}
```

> ed@swiftux:~/Swift/Scripts$ ./testReadline
>
> Enter your name:
>
> Eric
>
> Hello Eric!

`readline()` also works with `|` (the pipe):

> ed@swiftux:~/Swift/Scripts$ echo "Mike" | ./testReadline
>
> Enter your name:
>
> Hello Mike!

---

I've also tried the classic way with [NSFileHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24047046/2227743) but it's not implemented yet:

> fatal error: availableData is not yet implemented: file Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.swift

Comment: NSFileHandle is part of the Foundation framework.

Remember, Swift is the language that was open sourced by Apple, not iOS or any of the other frameworks that build up their proprietary OS

Comment: @Edwin Foundation is being implemented in Swift, open source, on GitHub. That's why I said NSFileHandle is not implemented *yet*, I was of course talking about Foundation, not about anything else and certainly not - you fool - about iOS or its SDKs. :p This is a Swift and Linux answer, nobody is talking about iOS here except you.

Comment: thanks for educating me on that, I should have read your reply to the end, I am surely lesser of a *fool* right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you import Glibc on Linux and Darwin.C on macOS, then you can read one line at a time using the `getline` function.

This requires a wee bit of c interop, but you can wrap it up to present a more Swifty interface. For instance, the following function returns a generator that iterates over lines read from a file stream:

```
#if os(Linux)
  import Glibc
#else
  import Darwin.C
#endif

func lineGenerator(file:UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>) -> AnyIterator<String>
{
  return AnyIterator { () -> String? in
    var line:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>? = nil
    var linecap:Int = 0
    defer { free(line) }
    let charactersWritten = getline(&line, &linecap, file)

    if charactersWritten > 0 {
      guard let line = line else { return nil }
      return String(validatingUTF8: line)
    }
    else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

This works on Swift 3. You can find a small [swiftecho example project](https://github.com/algal/swiftecho) which exercises this from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to read characters from `stdin`, however it's not beautiful but it shows what we can do by `Glibc`.

```
import Glibc

var buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>.alloc(32)

fread(buf, 1, 32, stdin)

// or

fgets(buf, 32, stdin)
```

and `buf` has the input characters.