# Reading input from keyboard in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, keyboard

I want to make an Cocoa aplication that take input from keyboard and does specific actions, depends on which button is pressed. What function(or anything) shoud I use?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004776/input-from-the-keyboard-in-command-line-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the NSResponder class documentation and there keyDown.