# User input in Xcode Playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm new to Swift and Xcode. I couldn't figure out how to take user input in Swift playground. I'm trying to write Swift equivalent of the following Python code:

```
def greet():
  name = raw_input('What is your name?>')
  print "Hello ", name
```

Is it possible to get user input in Swift playground?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Input from the keyboard in command line application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004776/input-from-the-keyboard-in-command-line-application)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `ask()` method which is available on Pad playgrounds