# Get user input from Swift 3 command line tool

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

When building a command line tool in Swift 3, I need to prompt the user for keyboard input. How would I go about asking a user for their input (e.g the users name)?

Comment: In particular this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34144018/1187415.

Answer (score 6):

`readline()` is available since at least Swift 2 and is still available in Swift 3 (Xcode 8 Beta 1):

```
print("Please enter your name: ", terminator: "")
let name = readLine()!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is subject to change as Swift 3 is a moving target, but here is a basic example to prompt a user for their input.

```
import Foundation

func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput()
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData

    return NSString(data: inputData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
}

print("Please enter your name:")

var name = input()

print("\(name)")
```

Comment: Note that with your solution, `name` will contain a trailing newline character.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Martin