# Method to get input in console swift

Tags: swift

How do I read input from console in swift as 'scanf() in c' and 'input() in python'.

I have tried

```
var ans = readline()
print(ans)
```

and its not working

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input from the keyboard in command line application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004776/input-from-the-keyboard-in-command-line-application)

Comment: You clearly haven't googled this before posting here.

Answer (score 3):

`readLine` *is* the right thing to use. The only possible reason why this does not work is that you're running it in a playground or some other place where the command prompt does not exist.

To make this work, simply create a new command line tool project. Go to "File" -> "New" -> "Project" -> "macOS" -> "Command Line Tool".

[image]

Now `readLine` should work.