# How to get input from the user in swift Xcode playgroud

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, input

Does swift have an input keyword or method like Java or C# or C++ to take input from the user in the Xcode playground?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input from the keyboard in command line application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004776/input-from-the-keyboard-in-command-line-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 5.1**

Go to "File" -> "New" -> "Project" -> "macOS" -> "Command Line Tool".

```
import Foundation

func input() -> String {
    let keyboard = FileHandle.standardInput
    let inputData = keyboard.availableData
    return String(data: inputData, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
}

if let number1 = readLine() , let number2 = readLine() {


var IntNum1 = Int(number1)
var IntNum2 = Int(number2)
}
```

Comment: why using `NSString` in Swift? And then downcasting to String. Use this instead: `return String(data: inputData, encoding: .utf8.rawValue)`