# lib.c and lib.h how to import this lib to swift source file

Tags: c, swift, xcode7

I have two files  : `lib.c` and `lib.h`. I need to use this C source code  in my `swift` code .

How to import these two C files?

Comment: in general: searching pays off

Answer (score 0):

There would be a ***lib-Bridging-Header.h*** file and you need to put your C function in that header. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004732/how-to-call-c-from-swift).