# How to get bytes out of an UnsafeMutableRawPointer?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

How does one access bytes (or Int16's, floats, etc.) out of memory pointed to by an UnsafeMutableRawPointer (new in Swift 3) handed to a Swift function by a C API (Core Audio, etc.)

Comment: Can you please give us a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of some concrete data to work with?

Comment: The [Swift Evolution proposal for `UnsafeRawPointer`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md) may be a good place to start – gives a good overview on the API with examples.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`load<T>` reads raw bytes from memory and constructs a value of type `T`:

```
let ptr = ... // Unsafe[Mutable]RawPointer
let i16 = ptr.load(as: UInt16.self)
```

optionally at a byte offset:

```
let i16 = ptr.load(fromByteOffset: 4, as: UInt16.self)
```

There is also `assumingMemoryBound()` which  converts from a `Unsafe[Mutable]RawPointer` to a `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<T>`, assuming that the pointed-to memory contains a value of type T:

```
let i16 = ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt16.self).pointee
```

For an array of values you can create a "buffer pointer":

```
let i16bufptr = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt16.self), count: count)
```

A buffer pointer might already be sufficient for your purpose, it 
is subscriptable and can be enumerated similarly to an array.
If necessary, create an array from the buffer pointer:

```
let i16array = Array(i16bufptr)
```

As @Hamish said, more information and details can be found at

- [SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)

Comment: Thanks!  That works for the 1st element.  How about for UInt16's (plural), as there could be an array of data?  (in an Int16 audio sample buffer, for example)

Comment: ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self).pointee = Int16(foo()) ; ptr += 2 // also seems to work for assigning to array elements sequentially

Comment: @hotpaw2: Yes, and that works also with `load`. The buffer pointer method is useful to assign an array of value in one step. Isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: How do you assign let ptr = ... // Unsafe[Mutable]RawPointer  in swift-3 .

Comment: when filling the buffer I get `Cannot assign through subscript, subscript is get only` error

Comment: `i16bufptr[0]=32`

Comment: @neckTwi: This question is about *reading* the bytes referenced by a raw pointer. If you want to mutate it then you need `let i16bufptr = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(...)`

Comment: @MartinR please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195022/what-is-replacement-of-cfreadstreamcreateforstreamedhttprequest

Answer (score 4):

Here's a Swift 4 example of converting a literal UInt8 array to an UnsafeMutableRawPointer and back to an UInt32 array

```
static func unsafePointerTest() {
    //let a : [UInt8] = [0,0,0,4,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,12]
    let a : [UInt8] = [0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                       0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                       0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00] //little endian
    //0xFF, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0x12]  //317780223 = 12F0F0FF
    let b:UnsafeMutableRawPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating:a)
    let bTypedPtr = b.bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: a.count/4)
    let UInt32Buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bTypedPtr, count: a.count/4)
    let output = Array(UInt32Buffer)
    print(output)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create **Data** object.

```
init(bytesNoCopy bytes: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, count: Int, deallocator: Data.Deallocator)
```

One important way missing from the other answers here is initialising a Data object with UnsafeMutableRawPointer. The data object can then be used for other calculations.

```
public func base64(quality: Int32 = 67) -> String? {
    var size: Int32 = 0
    if let image = gdImageJpegPtr(internalImage, &size, quality) {
        // gdImageJpegPtr returns an UnsafeMutableRawPointer that is converted to a Data object
        let d = Data(bytesNoCopy: image, count: Int(size), deallocator: .none)
        return d.base64EncodedString()
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: This came in very handy! I needed to change the dealloc to none, but this did the trick for me. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the api documentation of Unsafe[Mutable]RawPointer to T/Unsafe[MutablePointer] conversion:

```
/// Binds the allocated memory to type `T` and returns an
/// `UnsafePointer<T>` to the bound memory at `self`.
///
/// - Precondition: The memory is uninitialized.
/// - Postcondition: The memory is bound to 'T' starting at `self` continuing
///   through `self` + `count` * `MemoryLayout<T>.stride`
/// - Warning: Binding memory to a type is potentially undefined if the
///   memory is ever accessed as an unrelated type.
public func bindMemory<T>(to type: T.Type, capacity count: Int) -> UnsafePointer<T>

/// Converts from an `UnsafeRawPointer` to UnsafePointer<T> given that
/// the region of memory starting at `self` is already bound to type `T`.
///
/// - Precondition: The memory is bound to 'T' starting at `self` for some
///   unspecified capacity.
///
/// - Warning: Accessing memory via the returned pointer is undefined if the
///   if the memory has not been bound to `T`.
public func assumingMemoryBound<T>(to: T.Type) -> UnsafePointer<T>

/// Reads raw bytes from memory at `self + offset` and constructs a
/// value of type `T`.
///
/// - Precondition: The underlying pointer plus `offset` is properly
///   aligned for accessing `T`.
///
/// - Precondition: The memory is initialized to a value of some type, `U`,
///   such that `T` is layout compatible with `U`.
public func load<T>(fromByteOffset offset: Int = default, as type: T.Type) -> T
```

and then from `Unsafe[MutablePointer]<T>` to`T` can be converted with
`pointee` and `move` apis

```
/// Accesses the `Pointee` instance referenced by `self`.
///
/// - Precondition: the pointee has been initialized with an instance of
///   type `Pointee`.
public var pointee: Pointee { get }

/// Retrieves the `pointee`, returning the referenced memory to an
/// uninitialized state.
///
/// Equivalent to `{ defer { deinitialize() }; return pointee }()`, but
/// more efficient.
///
/// - Precondition: The pointee is initialized.
///
/// - Postcondition: The memory is uninitialized.
public func move() -> Pointee
```