# Convert NSData UnsafePointer operation to Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsdata, swift3

I am having a heck of a time converting my working NSData swift 2.2 code into 3.

I have a lot of errors that are all similar in one file, and I can't get it to compile to check my conversion. Here are the original lines:

```
let dataPtr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(bytes).advancedBy(f_offset)

let retVal = UnsafePointer<T>(dataPtr).memory
```

I think the first line gets converted to this:

```
let dataPtr = UnsafeRawPointer(bytes).advanced(by: f_offset)
```

I can't figure out how to convert the second line, because memory is not a member of UnsafeRawPointer, which Swift 3 seems to require.

How can I convert those two lines?

If I get more specific errors, I will post them.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983277/how-to-get-bytes-out-of-an-unsafemutablerawpointer

Comment: Thanks. Has helped a bit with a few other lines, but not with my main problems. I am working on a question update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `bytes` is taken from some `NSData`'s `bytes` property:

```
let bytes = nsData.bytes
```

Then you have no need to use `UnsafeRawPointer(_:)`:

```
let dataPtr = bytes.advanced(by: f_offset)
```

And may use a method of `UnsafeRawPointer`:

```
let retVal = dataPtr.load(as: T.self)
```