# How to create a typed pointer from an opaque pointer in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, pointers, swift3, unsafemutablepointer

Converting to Swift 3 I get the compiler error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' with
>   an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)'

when trying to create a typed pointer from an opaque pointer:

```
let imageRef = myUIImage.cgImage!
let context = CGContext(...)!
let rect = CGRect(...)
context.draw(imageref, in: rect)

var data = context.data
var dataType = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(data) //Throws the error
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: Compare [How to get bytes out of an UnsafeMutableRawPointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983277/how-to-get-bytes-out-of-an-unsafemutablerawpointer)

Answer (score 0):

`content.data` returns a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. It has a `bindMemory` and `assumingMemoryBound` methods to convert to typed pointers:

```
let dataType = data.bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: n) // UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
```

I don't have a chance to test what `n` is, but I suspect it will be something like this:

```
n = width * height * bitsPerPixel / 8
```