# Converting C pointers to Swift 3

Tags: ios, core-audio, swift3

I have the code:

```
let data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(audioBuffer.mData), count: Int(bufferSize))
```

and

```
let u16 = UnsafePointer<Int32>(audioBuffer.mData).pointee
```

Both of which work in Swift 2.3 but not in Swift 3. How do I convert them so they act equivalently? (and why?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983277/how-to-get-bytes-out-of-an-unsafemutablerawpointer , which answers how to get answer samples out of a Core Audio mData buffer in Swift 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read 16-bit audio samples from Audio Unit callback buffers in Swift 3, I use:

```
let bufferPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mBuffers.mData)
if var bptr = bufferPointer {
  for i in 0..<(Int(frameCount)) {
    let oneSampleI16 = bptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self).pointee
    // do something with the audio sample
    bptr += 1
  }
}
```

The rest of the Audio Session and Audio Unit code is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/630a466cc830e3d129b9

Comment: `++` operator has bee removed from Swift 3. Seems your code in the gist is written without using `++`, and I believe you can improve your code snippet in this answer.

Comment: @OOPer : Thanks.  Copy-paste error from old version fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I understand this well, [nor have I read the document](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md), but it looks like swift3 pointer casts are scoped to avoid or limit aliasing, so you *can't* (easily) have two different views  of the same piece of memory, or at least not for very long. This means you must either copy the cast data out or do whatever you need to do within a cast callback.

Why eliminate aliasing? I guess it makes for happier compilers.

For `Data`:

```
// [NS]Data. probably copying the data 
Data(bytes: audioBuffer.mData!, count: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))
```

For numeric arrays:

```
// cast the data to Int32s & (optionally) copy the data out
let umpInt32 = audioBuffer.mData!.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int32.self)

let frameCount = Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize/4)
var u32 = [Int32](repeating: 0, count: frameCount)

// copy data from buffer
u32.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer {
    $0.baseAddress!.initialize(from: umpInt32, count: frameCount)
}
```

p.s. there's some confusion in your code. is `u16` supposed to be an array of `Int32`s? Or `UInt16`s? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Check [the latest reference of `Data.init(bytes:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1780158-init).

The type of the parameter `bytes` is `UnsafeRawPointer`, which accepts `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. And the type of `AudioBuffer.mData` is `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`. You have no need to convert using initializer.

```
let data = Data(bytes: audioBuffer.mData!, count: Int(bufferSize))
```

(You just need to explicitly unwrap `mData`, as it is imported as nullable type, `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`, but you need to pass non-nil `UnsafeRawPointer` (or `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`).

---

The second example, you'd better check what sort of methods are available for `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. You can find `load(fromByteOffset:as:)` method, and can use it like this.

```
let i32 = audioBuffer.mData!.load(as: Int32.self)
```

`load(