# Swift 3 Unsafe Pointer

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3

I am migrating from Swift 2 to Swift 3 and I am stuck at one point.

**Swift 2**

```
let arr = UnsafePointer<UInt32>(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buf).advanced(by: off))
let msk = arr[0].bigEndian & 0x7fffffff
```

I get an error on first line saying

> 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to
>   temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.

I tried to use `withMemoryoRebound` method but I am not sure about the parameters.
As per [this docuentation](https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html#api-for-binding-memory-types-and-pointer-conversion), `UnsafePointer<>` has been replaced by `UnsafeRawPointer`. So I changed my code as below

```
let arr = UnsafeRawPointer(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buf).advanced(by: off))
let msk = arr[0].bigEndian & 0x7fffffff
```

But here on the second line it says

> Type 'UnsafeRawPointer' has no subscript members

How can I successfully convert it to Swift 3?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: [How to get bytes out of an UnsafeMutableRawPointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983277/how-to-get-bytes-out-of-an-unsafemutablerawpointer)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do that operation using withMemoryRebound:
Capacity in this case is 1, as you are only looking at the first element of the resulting array.

```
let arr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buf).advanced(by: off)
let msk = arr.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 1) { p in
    return p[0].bigEndian & 0x7fffffff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
let ppp = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(buf).advanced(by: off)
let arr = unsafeBitCast(ppp, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.self)
```