# Error 'init' is unavailable:use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type

Tags: ios, swift, memory

I'm migrating my code from swift 2 to swift 3 and i'm having this error 
for these lines

`let codeBuffer = UnsafePointer<UInt16>((buffer+offset))`

`let bytes = UnsafePointer<UInt64>((buffer+offset))`

how can i fix it using withMemoryRebound method ??

Comment: What type has `buffer`? Did you check the "Related" questions with the same title?

Comment: `let buffer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(frame!.mutableBytes).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)`   when 'let codeBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>((buffer+offset))`
yes I have checked couldn't get any answer

Comment: If you have a Unsafe(Mutable)RawPointer then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983277/how-to-get-bytes-out-of-an-unsafemutablerawpointer.