# How call assembly function from Swift

Tags: swift, function, assembly

In xcode 8.0 i have an s-file with an arm assembly block of code i've written.  I want to call this asm function and pass it a pointer - from my Swift code.  How do i do this?

Below is how i did the same thing in objective-c:

```
void my_asm_function(int *myptr);   //this is prototype in my h-file

my_asm_function(&myIntVar);  // this is how i call the function from my obj-c code
```

Comment: calling function implemented with assembly should be same as calling any C function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just call your function like any other C function...
Something like this should help you straightforward:
[How to call C from Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004732/how-to-call-c-from-swift)