# iOS include cross compiled C library : undefined symbols

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, shared-libraries

Full disclosure: total iOS development amateur here. My background is embedded firmware development.

TLDR: I'm trying to include a shared library, written in C, into a swift project, but getting "undefined symbols" errors

For a project, I'm trying to include a shared library written in C, that I manually cross compiled for ios-arm64 architecture (using `xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang -arch arm64` on a macbook ), and I'm trying to include this into a swift based iOS application: as the most simple example let's take the default swift application you get when starting a new iOS application in xcode.

If I understand correctly, the way I should approach this, is adding a target framework to the project (Editor > Add Target > Framework ) and then dragging my shared library (let's name it libcustom.dylib) and my header (custom.h) into the target framework. And then adding this custom header into the framework header file. I also set the framework settings to embed & sign the shared library.

Next, I try to call a function in this shared library in the ViewController.swift file. So what I do is import the framework header and then call the function, let's call it `perform_custom_action()` (xcode editor also autocompletes it), but when trying to build I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbol: _perform_custom_action
```

So there is a linking issue, probably it's not linking the library, but I dont know how I can link it in this xcode environment. I see in the compile output that it includes the framework, but I dont know if this framework is correctly including the library...

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

PS: some sanity checks:

libcustom.dylib is cross-compiled for arm64, output of `file libcustom.dylib` is:

`libcustom.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library arm64`

_perform_custom_action is part of the symbols inside libcustom.dylib, when executing `nm libcustom.dylib` I get

```
...
00000000005a544 T _perform_custom_action
...
```

EDIT: extra info:

- When creating the target framework, a bridging header is automatically created, after adding my own header to it, it looks like this:

```
//
//  custom_framework.h
//  custom_framework
//
//  Created by <user> on 13.01.22.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//! Project version number for custom_framework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double custom_frameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for custom_framework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char custom_frameworkVersionString[];

// In this header, you should import all the public headers of your framework using statements like #import <custom_framework/PublicHeader.h>

#import "custom_framework/custom.h"
```

EDIT2: when manually setting linker flags, namely:

- `Library Search Paths` : set to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/custom_framework`
- `Other Linker Flags` : set to `-lcustom`

Then it builds succesfully, so to me it looks like something is wrong in the framework

Comment: Try `nm -D libcustom.dylib | grep "_perform_custom_action"` and check if you get the same output.

Comment: Did you create the bridging header ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004732/how-to-call-c-from-swift

Comment: @kiner_shah do you mean `nm -gU libcustom.dylib | grep "_perform_custom_action` as osx has other flags than linux? That does return the expected output

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I updated my question with the content of the bridging header, that was auto-generated when creating the framework